# C++ inheritance and arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance

c++ newbie here

So I was checking out how classes work in c++, and I wrote this code:

```
class A{
   ...
}
class B: public A{
...
}
int main(void){
  A array[10];
}
```

Does inheritance in c++ work in the same way as inheritance in Java?
Can I add objects of type B in an array and if so how would I do that?
simply doing `array[0] = new B();` does not work

P.S. Just a follow-up question, can someone please show me a quick example of an array of objects of a class that has a simple constructor? For some reason I had issues with that. If it's sort of complicated I'll just post another question. Thanks in advance

Comment: You may use `A* array[10];` and then write `array[0] = new B();`. You can cast to base class only references and pointers of derived class. Simply doing `array[0] = new B();` not working because it is impossible to assign `A*` to `A`.

Comment: Java uses pointers (called references). If you use pointers in C++ it works the same way (roughly).

Comment: @wowofbob Thank you, I have just tried that And I'm indeed able to store that in an array, even if I have an object C

Comment: Java orject references are not exactly like C++ pointers nor C++ references, IMHO it is best to learn each separately

Comment: The simplest and most flexible way is `vector<unique_ptr<A>>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Java, a variable of a class type is always a reference to the object. I.e.

```
A a = new A();
A a2 = a; // now a and a2 represent the same object
a.x = 12; // now print(a2.x) will also output 12
```

`new A()` will create the actual object on the heap (area of memory that can be dynamically allocated), and return the memory address of it. `a` and `a2` will (internally) actually contain only that address.

Unlike integral type variables, which contain the actual value, so:

```
int a = 1;
int a2 = a;
a = 3;
// now a2 will still be 1
```

In C++ objects are put on the stack, the same way as integral types (unless you use references or pointers). So:

```
class A {
public:
   int x;
};

A a;
A a2;
a.x = 1;
a2 = a; // actually calls a2.operator=(a) which is implicitly defined, and assigns all data members (here only int x) the values from the other A
a.x = 2;
std::cout << a2.x << std::end; // will output 1
```

This is still true for arrays: If you declare an array `A as[10]`, as is a series of 10 A objects allocated on the stack.

### Inheritance

If you have

```
class A {
public:
    int x;
};
class B : public A {
public:
    int y;
};

A a;
a.x = 1;

B b;
b.x = 2;
b.y = 500;

// and then:
a = b; // now a.x == 2, but a holds no information about the y value

// with arrays it is the same:
A as[2];
as[0] = b; // now as[0].x == 2, --
```

Doing `a = b` copies only the values from `b` from its superclass, into `a`.

### References

```
A a;
a.x = 1;
A& a_ref = a;
```

now `a_ref` is a reference to `a`
unlike in Java the reference can't be made to point to another object.
Doing `a_ref = a2` would instead have the same effect as `a = a2`

```
a.x = 2
std::cout << a_ref.x << std::endl; // now outputs 2
```

Also unlike Java, `a` has to exist for as long as `a_ref` exist, otherwise `a_ref` is invalid and accessing it will make the program crash. In Java objects are allocated on the heap, and deallocated only when no reference exists that points to it anymore (this is called garbage collection).

```
B b;
A& a_ref2 = b;
// now a_ref2 is a reference to b.
// (aka B has been downcasted)
// to access b.y from a_ref2, you could do:
int the_y = static_cast<B&>(a_ref2).y
```

This (static upcasting), is not recommended and only works when you are sure that `a_ref2` points to a `B` object. Otherwise it fill segfault/crash.

If `A` is polymorphic (see below), `dynamic_cast<B&>(a_ref2)` can be used instead (still not recommended). It detects the error if `a_ref2` is not a `B` and throws an exception.

### Polymorphism

```
class A {
public:
    virtual int get_v() { return 1; }
    int get() { return 1; }
    int get_a() { return 3; }
};
class B : public A {
public:
    int get_v() override { return 2; } // 'override' is not needed, and only works in C++11
    int get() { return 2; }
};

B b;
A& a_ref = b;

b.get_v(); // returns 2
b.get(); // returns 2
b.get_a(); // returns 3, by inheritance

a_ref.get_v(); // returns 2, because get_v is a virtual function.
```

Because of the virtual function  A and B are polymorphic classes. It is not known at compile time whether this will call `A::get_v` or `B::get_v`, since `a_ref` is of type `A&`. Instead the function to call is decided at runtime, depending on what `a_ref` points to. In Java all functions are like this.

```
a_ref.get(); // returns 1.
```

Because `get()` is not polymorphic, it calls `A`'s `get()` function since `a_ref` is of type `A&`.

```
a_ref.get_a(); // returns 3, by inheritance
```

### Pointers

Pointers are like references, but lower level. You access references the same way as actual objects (`a_ref.x` and `b.x`). The pointer variable is the address. Unlike references, they can be made to point to another object after initial assignment:

```
B b; // same classes A and B as before
A* a_ptr = &b; // a is now a pointer to b.
// The type A* means "pointer to B". &b means "address of b".

// Polymorphism works the same:
a_ptr->get_v(); // returns 2
a_ptr->get(); // returns 1.
a_ptr->get_a(); // returns 3.
```

Dynamic memory allocation also returns pointers:

```
A* a_ptr = new B(); // a_ptr is now a pointer to a B allocated on the heap
...
delete a_ptr; // must be done to deallocate the B, otherwise there will be a memory leak.
```

Because a_ptr is of type `A*` (and not `B*`), the destructor of a polymorphic class should be virtual:

```
class A {
public:
    ...
    virtual ~A() { .... }
};
class B : public A {
public:
    ...
    ~B() override { .... }
};
```

otherwise only `A::~A` would get called.

So in your case, you could do:

```
A* array[10];
array[0] = new B();

array[0]->get_v();
delete array[0];
```

But all the pointers in the array that haven't been initialized would be invalid. I.e. `array[1]->get_v()` or `delete array[1]` would be an error.

`array` would then be an array of pointers to objects of type `A`, or a subclass of `A`.

You can also dynamically allocate an array of A's like this:

```
A* array = new[10] A; // array is now a pointer to an array
array[0].x = 1;
delete[] array; // Deallocates as many items as where allocated
```

But this is the same as doing `A as[10]` as before, just on the stack. These would be `A` objects , and doing `array[0] = b` would just copy the `b.x` from `b`.

### unique_ptr

A good solution would probably to use `std::unique_ptr` from the STL. It is a wrapper for a pointer, such that no two `unique_ptr` can point to the same item. (because copying the `unique_ptr` is forbidden, etc.):

```
#include <memory>
// needed for std::unique_ptr

std::unique_ptr<A> array[10];
array[0].reset( new B() ); // needed to assign a value to it
array[0]->get_v();
```

works as expected. The elements of `array` that have not been assigned a value are default-initialized to zero. Accessing them would throw an exception instead of a segfault etc.

Items can't be assigned with `=` (because the semantics are different). Instead, `reset` assigns the pointer. If it had another pointer before, that one is `delete`'d first. Also no `delete array[0]` are needed (or possible), the `unique_ptr` deletes the items when the variable `array` goes out of scope.

A solution to allow multiple pointers pointing to the same object, such that the object gets deallocated only when no pointer points to it anymore, is also in the STL: `shared_ptr`.

### Array constructors

For an array of items on the stack like

```
A array[10];
```

It will always call the default constructor (with no arguments). There is no way to pass arguments to it.

`std::array` can be copy-initialized (i.e. constructor taking single value:)

```
class A {
public:
    int x;
    A(int nx) : x(nx) {}
};

std::array<A, 3> ar = { 1, 2, 3 };
// or
std::array<A, 2> ar2 = { a, a2 }; // makes copies
```

Comment: Solid answer, albeit a tad long